# Как сделать растягивание определенного количества блоков по всей ширине?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно сделать такую витрину работ. Суть в том, что в ряду может быть максимум 4 работы вне зависимости от ширины экрана, т.е. этих 4 блока должны растягиваться по всей ширине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как я пытался это сделать, но остается свободное место, не растягиваются блоки по всей ширине, но это и логично, ведь я задал им максимальную ширину в примере (это для того что бы блок не растягивался по всей ширине картинки, ибо картинки большого размера).

```css
.works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.element {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 2px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Сниппет: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvMBOK

Как выглядит в реальной верстке (Для лучшего понимания того, что нужно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным отмечена область от которой нужно избавиться. В итоге задача состоит в том, чтобы максимум в ряду было 4 блока и чтобы не оставалось место.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так? Если по-простому без бубнов. Но тут будет фиксированное количество блоков 4 и ширина 25%.

```css
.works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.element {
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="element"><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/953/28107506758_5fbb9dfdd0_b.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```